# Add today's date as URL query string to external site in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, string

I want to add in today's date as a query string parameter in a Wordpress site.

I've got a booking link URL which unfortunately won't accept a request without a valid date.

http://bookingsiteurl.com/search?Date=2017-08-08&Service=ABC&Currency=USD

Is there any way to setup a custom function that can make today's date as a URL parameter universally available on my site?

Maybe in the format of a hidden field populated with today's date, that I can then reference in URLs similar to how many of the common form plugins can add form fields into a query string.

Eg.

http://bookingsiteurl.com/search?Date={TODAYS_DATE}&Service=ABC&Currency=USD

Is this possible with custom function?

Comment: Yes, but that depends on how you "render" the url in your html. Please post an example of server side code that creates the url.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this functionality using [rewrite api](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API) in wordpress.

Create URL by daily based using wp-cron. Create one function that create a permalink by add_rewrite_url. After successfully create custom endpoint Call flush_rewrite_rules(), Then only your custom endpoint will work.

Refer below links for more details,

Rewrite_API : https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-rewrite-api-the-basics--wp-25474

WP-CRON : https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/10/schedule-events-using-wordpress-cron/